# PHP htmlspecialchars issue with email

Tags: php, email, htmlspecialchars

My problem is that htmlspecialchars is not answering when sending email.

So when I enter contact.php?reklamtion=yes (for example), everything looks fine. 
echo $formproc gives me ?reklamation=yes.

What should happen in this case is that a mail should be sent to everytime@example.com and reklamation@example.com.

Instead what happens is that a mail is sent to everytime@example.com and fail@example.com, and when redirected $formproc echoes ?none=yes.

Do anyone know what's wrong here, or where I should start looking?

```
<?php
$frompage = "";

$formproc->AddRecipient('everytime@example.com');

if (htmlspecialchars($_GET["reception"])=="yes") {
$formproc->AddRecipient('reception@example.com');
$frompage = "&reception=yes";

} elseif (htmlspecialchars($_GET["reklamation"])=="yes") {
$formproc->AddRecipient('reklamation@example.com');
$frompage = "&reklamation=yes";

} elseif (htmlspecialchars($_GET["contact1"])=="yes") {
$formproc->AddRecipient('contact1@example.com');
$frompage = "&contact1=yes";

} elseif (htmlspecialchars($_GET["contact2"])=="yes") {
$formproc->AddRecipient('contact2@example.com');
$frompage = "&contact2=yes";

} else {
$formproc->AddRecipient('fail@example.com');
$frompage = "&none=yes";
}

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $formproc->RedirectToURL(" $actual_link?sent=yes$frompage ");
   }
}
?>

...

<html>
    <body>
        <?php 
        echo $formproc
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        die($frompage); // This gives back &none=yes on submit
        $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $formproc->RedirectToURL(" $actual_link?sent=yes$frompage ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using htmlspecialchars in any case here? What is the result of die( htmlspecialchars($_GET["reception"]) ); ?

Comment: Is there another solution then htmlspecialchars when I send variables through URL? die does the same as echo $formproc. Works great first time, but when I send an email it stops working.